# How to send back an image in Go from the public folder?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm new to go if it's an obvious question then sorry but I didn't find anything so I'm posting here.

This is a two-part question actually.

1) So I have this web folder in my project dir. And it is public and I have a middleware function which is checking for the JWT.

I'm using this logic to avoid JWT auth but it's now working. I'm getting `unauthorized`.

```
// List of endpoints that don't require auth by an access token
        notAuth := []string{"/", "/refreshtokens", "/students/signup", "/students/signin", "/students/forgotpassword",
            "/images"}

        // Current request path
        requestPath := r.URL.Path

        // Check if the request does not need authentication, serve the request if it doesn't need it
        for _, value := range notAuth {

            if value == requestPath {
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
                return
            }
        }
```

So how can I put this URL inside the array so it can escape the JWT authorization?

2) This is how I'm making the folder public but I don't want this.

```
router.PathPrefix("/images").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/images", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web/"))))
```

What I want is something like

```
router.Handle("/image/{imageName}",func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request){
http.ServeFile(this image name file)
})
```

So I can send back the file which is requested.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1: clearly the request path is not one of those in `notAuth`. Maybe you need to check if the path has a prefix that is included in `notAuth`? If that is so, you need to be careful about `/`, as it will pass all paths. If not, log the request path and see what the problem is.

For #2: you should be able to do:

```
http.ServeFile(w,request,filepath.Join(baseDir,mux.Vars(request)["imageName"])
```

Comment: How can I do this `prefix` thing?

Comment: You can do: `if strings.HasPrefix(requestPath,value)` to check if `requestPath` has a prefix `value`. Make sure the `notAuth` paths end with /, otherwise any matching prefix will work. Also, `/` cannot be in `notAuth` as it will let everything pass.

Comment: It's working! But image is not opening it's downloading.

Comment: You need to set the correct Content-Type in the response. If you set the content type to the correct image mime type, it should display the image.

Comment: Yeah but it's already `w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")`

Comment: It also matters when you set that header. It should be set before sending anything to the client.

Comment: Yeah! Postman is showing those headers. But still having this issue

Comment: If the response has Content-Type: image/jpeg, then the client should be able to display the image. I'd check if there something amiss on the client side.

Comment: Please check! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood? I meant "you should check on the client side".

Comment: I'm using postman! What should I check? I tried chrome and it's showing me the download prompt.

Comment: This is difficult to do without the knowledge of the setting, however, you can check if there is a Content-Disposition header, that affects download behavior; you can check other headers. You can try different browsers and/or plugins and try to understand why it is downloading the image instead of displaying it.

Comment: Okay, I'll post here! If I get something!

Comment: Interesting! Mozilla is letting me show the image but chrome is not.